# Unmarshalling complex types using single JAXB annotated class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following xml to be consumed by my application:

```
<PackageFiles ApplicationGUID="839E9EFD-69C2-430D-B591-B9C8E9812377">
  <Files>
    <File Name="test.jpg" />
  </Files>
</PackageFiles>
```

To unmarshall with JAXB I've defined the following two classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="PackageFiles")
public class PackageFiles {

    @XmlAttribute(name="ApplicationGUID")
    private String applicationGUID;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Files")
    @XmlElement(name="File")
    private List<File> files;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="File")
public class File {

    @XmlAttribute(name="Name")
    private String name;
}
```

This works great but I was wondering is there a way to annotate the `PackageFiles` class so that I can eliminate the `File` class and instead have the `Name` attribute in the `<File ...>` element be populated into a `List<String>` in the PackageFiles class?

Answer (score 1):

If this sort of complication comes up often, you may consider using a Transformer that uses xslt to perform the unmarshalling in a way that you can easily manipulate.  Either that or you can make file a public static class inside PackageFiles like so:

```
public static class File{
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
}
```

Personally I prefer the xslt method because it's a bit more intuitive and a lot easier to maintain than .java files that are in a constant state of flux.